# Express - Firebase - Check undefined req.cookie.__session without throwing error

Tags: javascript, firebase, express, cookies

I have an express backend that checks if req.cookie.__session is undefined.  If it is then I want it to return `res.status(200).json({ verification: false });`  if it is not undefined then I want it to check the cookie with `jwt.verify()` and handle it otherwise.

The problem is that if it is undefined then my try/catch catches and throws "Cannot read property '__session' " instead of returning the response that I want which is the ...verification: false.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

```
    try {
             let token = req.cookies.__session;
                console.log("req.cookies.__session", token);
                if (!token) {
                  console.log("no token cookie");
                  return res.status(200).json({ verification: false });
                }
                ... further code to verify and handle token if not undefined
         } catch (err) {...error handles}
```

Comment: Did you forget to inject the [cookie-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-parser) middleware in your request handling pipeline? `req.cookies` is not a part of the base express library.

Comment: It was as simple as that, thanks.